# YouTube API Multi-Channel Network Stats?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I'm looking to obtain basis MCN stats to retrieve info such as:
Total Network Subscribers & Total Network Views

Does anyone know if this is possible & (ideally)
what the query would be to retrieve in JSON ?